# How would you model a quadratic or cubic growth?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to model a rate of growth that is lower than an exponential one and would like some help.

If we want to model an exponential growth it would be something like this, where m is number of years, D the variable and c is a constant of integration:

### $\frac{\frac{dD}{dm}}{D}=a$

$\int \frac{dD}{D}= \int a dm $

$ln(D)=c+am $

$ e^{ln(D)}=  e^{c+am}$

$ D=  e^{c}e^{am}$

This in a graph would appear as an exponential growth of D. Is there any way to change this into a quadratic or cubic growth? In other words, is there any way to make the growth rate lower?

Thank you.

Comment: if you want a quadratic growth, then the derivative dD/dm must be proportional to m (not D).  Try it!

Comment: You have to derive a differential equation for $D(m)=cm^2$ and $D(m)=cm^3$

Comment: for example dD/dm = am +b   .  Separate and integrate.

Comment: for cubic growth rate, dD/dm = am^2 + bm + c  will work

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot. I'll try doing it.

Comment: Would the cubic growth rate be something like this? $D= \frac{1}{3}m(am^2+3b)$